# If $x > 1$ then does the set $ \lbrace{ \lbrace{ x^n\rbrace}: n\in\mathbb{N} \rbrace}\ $ always contain either $0$ or $1$ as a limit point?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fractional-part, equidistribution

This question is somewhat related to my previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4564934/classification-of-real-numbers-x-1-such-that-xn-n-in-mathbb).

Here, $\lbrace{ \cdot \rbrace}$ means fractional part.

Is it true that if $x > 1\ $ then either $0$ or $1$ (or both) are accumulation points of the set $ A_x:= \lbrace{\ \lbrace{\ x^n \rbrace}: n\in\mathbb{N}\ \rbrace}\ ?$

I think this is true for Pisot Numbers at least, because, for example, $(3+\sqrt{5})^n + (3-\sqrt{5})^n \in\mathbb{Z}.\ $ and $\ \vert 3-\sqrt{5}\vert < 1.$

Also relevant is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Complete_uniform_distribution), where it says,

> The sequence $\displaystyle (\alpha ,\alpha ^{2},\alpha ^{3},\dots )$
> is completely uniformly distributed for *almost all* $\alpha >1.$

Unfortunately this does not decide whether or not $A_x$ contains either $0$ or $1$ as a limit point for *every* $x>1.$ And also the above fact does not tell us that it is not known whether or not $0$ or $1$ is a limit point of $A_x$ for every $x>1.$ So the question remains.

I have some vague idea about considering the interval $(\liminf A_x, \limsup A_x)$ and coming to a contradiction, but I don't have anything concrete yet.

Comment: What about the rational case , say , $x=\frac{3}{2}$ ?

Comment: @Peter yes, that is a part of my question. I am not sure what is known about $x=3/2$ and as part of my question I am asking if anyone knows about it.

Comment: Maybe $0$ and $1$ are not special in the set of limit points ? So this question shouldn't expect any sort known results?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I don't think it is equidistributed for any irrational number; as you have said, take the golden ratio for example.

Comment: Also, I remember plotting the distribution for $x=e$ and it was very weird, in fact, I think it didn't have any distribution... (in the limit). It was dense anyway. But, it did have some structure. It's only that this structure didn't converge, it was changing all the time. Try plotting it, maybe you discover something more.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I think, I mixed this with $nx$ which is obviously equidistributed.